# Getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error even when .class file exists

Tags: java

This is my file structure:

```
T1 -> T1sample -> src -> t1sample -> T1.java
T1 -> T1sample -> src -> t1sample -> T1.class
```

I created these folders and files myself (except for T1.class, I got that by running 'javac T1.java' from the shell).

This is T1.java:

```
package t1sample;

public class T1 {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        System.out.println('Test');
    }
}
```

Now when I try to run `java T1` it returns an error saying:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  T1 (wrong name: t1sample/T1)
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Try running >  `java t1sample.T1`

Comment: What directory are you running the java command from?

Comment: @EddieB I get a `Error: Could not find or load main class t1sample.T1` error.

Comment: @SualehFatehi From `T1/T1sample/src/t1sample`

Comment: Did you _compile_? ` ~ javac T1.java

Comment: @EddieB Yup, I ran `javac T1.java` which created the `T1.class` file, and then ran `java T1` and `java t1sample.T1`.

Comment: Try starting over... worked for me mate..

Comment: @EddieB When you tried, did you create the folders and files with shell (i.e. `mkdir`)? Not using Eclipse? Because I didn't use Eclipse.

Comment: Run `java t1sample.T1` command from the `T1sample/src`  directory ...

Comment: @EddieB Ah okay, that works. Any idea what `java T1` was not working from inside `t1sample`?

Comment: Yes... you have a `package` declaration :) which means that `t1sample` is a package so you have to run the class from the `root` ( src ) directory ( see my answer )

Comment: re "ah okay...any idea" -- the short answer is that it's simply not how it works.  Although there is a relation to package and subdirectory when dealing with "loose" .class files (vs. classes packaged in a JAR or other archive), there is no concept of finding a class 'relative' to the current directory (i.e. there is no ./T1 -- it's name is t1sample.T1 and java will try to find it as ./t1sample/T1.class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for clarification the reason your getting a [**NoClassDefFoundError**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) is because you declared `t1sample` as a **package**. Therefore T1 has to be run from the `src` directory, not from `t1sample`.

First create the directory structure... (Using gvim as an editor)

```
~/Desktop $ mkdir -p T1sample/src/t1sample && cd T1sample/src/t1sample && gvim T1.java
```

Create the source...

```
package t1sample;

public class T1 {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Test"); 
    }
}
```

Compile ...

```
~/Desktop $  cd T1sample/src/t1sample/
~/Desktop/T1sample/src/t1sample $  javac T1.java
```

Confirm...

```
~/Desktop/T1sample/src/t1sample $  ls -la
total 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 Edward None 411 Sep 28 21:46 T1.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 Edward None 137 Sep 28 21:45 T1.java
```

Run it from the src directory...

```
~/Desktop/T1sample/src/t1sample $  cd ..
~/Desktop/T1sample/src $  java t1sample.T1
Test
```